# Set builder notation error for my own zip implementation

Tags: haskell

So I'm learning haskell right now, and I'm having trouble understanding what I'm doing wrong for the following function that emulates `zip`

1.`ziplike xs ys = [(x,y)|c<-[0..(min (length xs) (length ys))-1],x<-xs!!c,y<-ys!!c]`

2.`ziplike xs ys = [(xs!!c,ys!!c)|c<-[0..(min (length xs) (length ys))-1]]`

Now, I know that the correct answer is number 2, but I don't understand why number 1 is wrong for the call `ziplike [1,2,3] ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`. I THINK it's because it's trying to select the index for an individual char, but I'm not sure why.

The error is "Couldn't match expected type ‘[t1]’ with actual type ‘Char’"

Comment: `x <- xs !! c` works only if `xs !! c` is a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a type error.

When you write "x from xs get-index c" (i.e. `x <- xs !! c`) the thing that you are getting "from" `xs !! c` is not necessarily a list. It's a technical detail, but it's important. The "from" arrow comes from monad syntax/`do`-notation. A list comprehension is actually just a do-expression specialized to the List monad; so the right hand side of an arrow `<-` needs to be a list in the List monad.

You can fix this, first off, by "cheating" with singleton lists, a la:

```
ziplike xs ys = [ (x,y) | c <- [0 .. min (length xs) (length ys) - 1], 
                          x <- [xs !! c], 
                          y <- [ys !! c]]
```

So these left-arrows are not "let" variable bindings, but they make Cartesian products: but the Cartesian product of n things with 1 thing with 1 thing is just `n * 1 * 1 == n` things. So this is great, if a little weird and possibly inefficient.

To do what you were trying to do (bind x and y inside of the list comprehension) you could also write something like:

```
ziplike xs ys = [let x = xs !! c; y = ys !! c in (x, y) 
                | c <- [0 .. min (length xs) (length ys) - 1]]
-- or --
ziplike xs ys = [(x, y) 
                | c <- [0 .. min (length xs) (length ys) - 1],
                  let x = xs !! c, let y = ys !! c]
-- or --
ziplike xs ys = [(x, y) 
                | c <- [0 .. min (length xs) (length ys) - 1],
                  let x = xs !! c; y = ys !! c]
```

Notice that these are all do-notation ideas tacked together with commas. Of course all of these look more clumsy than

```
ziplike xs ys = [(xs !! c, ys !! c) | c <- [0..min (length xs) (length ys) - 1]
```

which does the exact same thing.

With that said, all of this stuff is **much** more inefficient than the `zip` function's recursive character: if I double the size of the list, your implementations take 4 times as long to process the whole list; `zip` only takes twice as long. So be mindful of this "hidden O(n<sup>2</sup>) factor" in your programming.

Comment: Would you mind explaining that one paragraph about Cartesian products? I didn't really understand it :(

Comment: The [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of [1,2,3] and [4,5,6] is the set of pairs [(1,4), (1,5), (1,6), (2,4), (2,5), (2,6), (3,4), (3,5), (3,6)]. You can obtain this Cartesian product in Haskell by writing `[(x, y) | x <- [1,2,3], y <- [4, 5, 6]]`. A Cartesian product of two sets, A and B, has cardinality `|A × B| = |A| |B|`, the product of the cardinalities of A and B. If one of the sets contains only one element, like `{1, 2, 3} × {4}`, then there will be 3 elements to the resulting list and you can think of the adjoined 4 as a "local variable".

Answer (score 5):

To a first approximation:

If `e::[a]`,
and `x <- e` appears to the right of the `|` in a list comprehension,
then `x :: a` wherever it is bound.

This leads to a bit of a problem in your case. You have `ys :: [Char]` and `c :: Int`, so that `ys!!c :: Char`. Hence:

We have `ys!!c :: Char`
and `y <- ys!!c` appears to the right of the `|` in a list comprehension,
so `y :: ???` wherever it is bound.

But now we are stuck when trying to write the conclusion about what type `y` should have: `Char` is not a list of `a`s, no matter what `a` we pick.

There are several possible fixes; one is to use `let` instead of `<-`, as in

```
ziplike xs ys = [(x,y)|c<-[0..min (length xs) (length ys)-1],let x=xs!!c; y=ys!!c]
```

Comment: So, I'm still learning Haskell and I'm not entirely familiar with the jargon yet (namely ```::```).  From my understanding, you're saying that e needs to be a list of arbitrary elements, but since ```ys!!c``` is of type char, and not a list, it essentially won't work?

Therefore, by using ```let```, we can force x and y to be variables.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @AnubhawArya You can pronounce `::` as "has type". You are correct in your second sentence. `x` and `y` are variables whether you bind them with `let` or `<-`; the difference is that `let` simply gives another name for an expression whereas `<-` also has some less trivial meaning: `x <- e` allows `x` to take on each of the values that are elements of the list `e` in sequence.